# How to convert object-like file content to JSON string in PHP

Tags: php, json, serialization

I have a file with content like

```
{
  property1: {
    property2: [
      'value1',
      'value2',
    ],
  },
}
```

and I get such file content via `file_get_contants()`.

How then to convert the content to JSON string i.e. to

```
{
  "property1": {
    "property2": [
      "value1",
      "value2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Maybe there is a ready solution instead of writing one more code with REGEXs and `str_replace()`s?

Comment: What is this format ? Where does it come from ? Maybe it should be generated in valid JSON in the first place.

Comment: You should be able to use any Yaml parser for it, then convert back to JSON in code

Comment: Wow! @iainn  I would have never thought of that http://www.yamllint.com/